# Google Cloud Dataflow - Java SDK vs Python SDK

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm starting to use Google Cloud Dataflow for batch and streaming processing. The jobs being developed are mostly for ingesting data from different sources (MySQL, Kafka, and file systems), cleansing them, do some streaming and bath aggregation, and writing back to Google Cloud Storage.

Given these tasks, are there any recommendations for using the **Java SDK** or **Python SDK** for writing the jobs? Any noticeable differences in terms of performance and features between them?

For example, I noticed that for the Java SDK, the built-in I/O `PTransform` **JdbcIO** is available. This `PTransform` reads and writes data on JDBC, and this is not available in the Python SDK (so far). Is it possible to use the Java SDK only to create a pipeline that reads from a MySQL database and writes to Google Cloud Storage, while for the other pipelines use a different SDK (e.g. Python)?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the Python SDK for development. While there is the built-in `PTransform` *JdbcIO* in the Java SDK, there are some community packages, such as `beam-nuggets` available for `python`, which can be used for reading from and writing to `MySQL`. This is what I have been using to develop ETLs.

The link for the package: https://pypi.org/project/beam-nuggets/

Overall, there are more features in the Java SDK.

If you are more comfortable with `python`, you can definitely write some pipelines in `java` that require the use of certain unique features, and the rest in `python`.

Comment: It does not seem to provide any support for Cloud SQL Proxy. So, I am not sure how people could use it in production.

Answer (score 2):

I would go ahead with `java` SDK as the features and external connectors are more in java. But `python` SDK is also catching up.

As far as performance considerations are concerned when we submit a beam job to dataflow, the job steps will be sent in an API call to the google cloud dataflow. Hence, I think there's no significant difference in performance as far as dataflow is concerned

Comment: It should be noted that there's a PR out to add JDBC IO (among others) in Python via multi-language support, which will allow the choice of language(s) more based on what libraries/ecosystem/tooling you have and less on what features are available. https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/12145